# How can I extend Scala collections with member values?

Tags: scala

Say I have the following data structure:

```
case class Timestamped[CC[M] < Seq[M]](elems : CC, timestamp : String)
```

So it's essentially a sequence with an attribute -- a timestamp -- attached to it. This works fine and I could create new instances with the syntax

```
val t = Timestamped(Seq(1,2,3,4),"2014-02-25")
t.elems.head // 1
t.timestamp  // "2014-05-25"
```

The syntax is unwieldly and instead I want to be able to do something like:

```
Timestamped(1,2,3,4)("2014-02-25")
t.head      // 1
t.timestamp // "2014-05-25"
```

Where timestamped is just an extension of a `Seq` and it's implementation `SeqLike`, with a single attribute `val timestamp : String`.

This seems easy to do; just use a `Seq` with a mixin `TimestampMixin { val timestamp : String }`. But I can't figure out how to create the constructor. **My question is: how do I create a constructor in the companion object, that creates a sequence with an extra member value?** The signature is as follows:

```
object Timestamped {
  def apply(elems: M*)(timestamp : String) : Seq[M] with TimestampMixin = ???
}
```

You'll see that it's not straightforward; collections use `Builder`s to instantiate themselves, so I can't simply call the constructor an override some `val`s.

Answer (score 2):

Scala collections are very complicated structures when it comes down to it. Extending `Seq` requires implementing `apply`, `length`, and `iterator` methods. In the end, you'll probably end up duplicating existing code for `List`, `Set`, or something else. You'll also probably have to worry about `CanBuildFrom`s for your collection, which in the end I don't think is worth it if you just want to add a field.

Instead, consider an implicit conversion from your `Timestamped` type to `Seq`.

```
case class Timestamped[A](elems: Seq[A])(timestamp: String)

object Timestamped {
    implicit def toSeq[A](ts: Timestamped[A]): Seq[A] = ts.elems
}
```

Now, whenever I try to call a method from `Seq`, the compiler will implicitly convert `Timestamped` to `Seq`, and we can proceed as normal.

```
scala> val ts = Timestamped(List(1,2,3,4))("1/2/34")
ts: Timestamped[Int] = Timestamped(List(1, 2, 3, 4))

scala> ts.filter(_ > 2)
res18: Seq[Int] = List(3, 4)
```

There is one major drawback here, and it's that we're now stuck with `Seq` after performing operations on the original `Timestamped`.

Comment: Consider this plan B.

Comment: I think Seq extension can be complicated if you need to construct them from scratch, but extending Seq and passing through the 3 abstract members to an existing implementation works fine. The non-abstract members just use those 3 methods in their default implementation I expect.

Comment: True, but methods that return collections will still return `Seq` as is the case here. My point is that if he wants a `map` that returns `Timestamped[A]`, then it will be quite difficult.

Comment: Yes, as @m-z states, I want it to look like a new collection type. The first thing I tried was implementing a `Builder` and `CanBuildFrom`; however, trying to extend existing implementation of `Builder` doesn't appear to work, as these are qualified `final`, so I can't override the constructor to accept my new `timestamp` member.

Answer (score 0):

Go the other way... extend Seq, it only has 3 abstract members:

```
  case class Stamped[T](elems: Seq[T], stamp: Long) extends Seq[T] {
    override def apply(i: Int) = elems.apply(i)
    override def iterator = elems.iterator
    override def length = elems.length
  }

  val x = Stamped(List(10,20,30), 15L)

  println(x.head)              // 10
  println(x.timeStamp)         // 15
  println(x.map { _ * 10})     // List(100, 200, 300)
  println(x.filter { _ > 20})  // List(30)
```

Keep in mind, this only works as long as Seq is specific enough for your use cases, if you later find you need more complex collection behavior this may become untenable.

**EDIT: Added a version closer to the signature you were trying to create. Not sure if this helps you any more:**

```
  case class Stamped[T](elems: T*)(stamp: Long) extends Seq[T] {
    def timeStamp = stamp
    override def apply(i: Int) = elems.apply(i)
    override def iterator = elems.iterator
    override def length = elems.length
  }  

  val x = Stamped(10,20,30)(15L)

  println(x.head)              // 10
  println(x.timeStamp)         // 15
  println(x.map { _ * 10})     // List(100, 200, 300)
  println(x.filter { _ > 20})  // List(30)
```

Where elems would end up being a generically created `WrappedArray`.

Comment: Thanks @Rich Henry. The implementation does appear simpler. But like you say, this would force the implementation to use `Seq`. What I really wanted was something like `GenTraversableFactory` trait - see scaladoc. All the concrete collections companion objects extend this to get an almost free Factory implementation.

Comment: Following up on the above, I appreciate I didn't specify that clearly in the question (That's why the first code snippet had `CC <: Seq`, as in the implementation of GenTraversableFactory). Maybe I need to clarify this. Thanks for your update though.

Comment: In your code, `CC` will have to be a `Seq`, just like mine, assuming the `<` was supposed to be a `<:` or `<%`. Without extending a collection trait/class, using an implicit like @m-z showed above, or implementing the methods manually -- your class will never act like a collection as shown in your question.